# Enabling input field based on checkbox flag in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to enable an input field based on the checkbox value, but I am failing. Please help.

```
sap.ui.define([
   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",

], function (Controller) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App", {
       new sap.m.CheckBox("extended-checkbox",{
          selected:  false,
          enabled:  true,
        }),

        new sap.m.Input(extended-checkbox.getSelected(tue), {
          value: "EUR",
          visible:true,
        })

});
});
```

Comment: What does it mean "I am failing"? That is not any error code. Please be specific. Also please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: @MaciejJureczko the code is not returning the desired output.

Comment: What is it returning then?

Comment: @MaciejJureczko it's blank. Pasting the view-code below.              

<mvc1:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc1="sap.ui.core.mvc1">

<CheckBox text="Test" selected="true" enabled="true" />
 
      
</mvc1:View>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activating an input field based on checkbox flag in SAPUI5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46424070/activating-an-input-field-based-on-checkbox-flag-in-sapui5)