# Activating an input field based on checkbox flag in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am trying to activate an input field based on the checkbox flag. The input field is not getting activated. Please help.
  Below are the snippets from the view and the component.

View------------------------------------------

```
<mvc1:View
   controllerName="sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App"
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc1="sap.ui.core.mvc1">

<CheckBox id="ch1" text="Test" selected="false" select ="checkDone" enabled="true" />

<Input  id="i1" enabled="false"></Input>

</mvc1:View>
```

Controller---------------------------------------

```
sap.ui.define([
                   "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
                ], function (Controller) {
                   "use strict";
                   return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App",{
                       checkDone: function (oEvent) {
                           var check = oEvent.getParameter("selected");
                            if (check === true){
                             sap.m.Input({id:"i1",
                                enabled:"true",
                                label: "Amount",
                                textAlign: sap.ui.core.TextAlign.Right,
                                value: "INR"
                             });
                           }else {
                                return "";
                           }
                        }
                   }); 
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the enbaled property from the input field to the model value of the checkbox. Then if you check the box it should automatically en-/disable the input field.

Something like this:

```
<CheckBox id="ch1" text="Test" selected="false" select ="checkDone" value="{someModel>/enabledValue}" enabled="true" />

<Input  id="i1" enabled="{someModel>/enabledValue}"></Input>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
             checkDone: function (oEvent) {
                 var check = oEvent.getParameter("selected");
                  if (check){
                   this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(true);
                 }else{
                   this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(false);
                 }
              }
```

**Check with the above code**

For place holder inside input

**This is not the preferred way but...**

```
<Input  id="i1" enabled="false" class="placeholder"></Input>

onAfterRendering : function(){
   $(".placeholder .sapMInputBaseInner").attr("placeholder", "Your placeholder Text");
}
```

Comment: @santosh,  thanks, I would also like to add  some default value in the input field like Name1, Address 1, in a manner that once user starts writing, the default value gets auto-omitted. Any clue on this aspect?

Comment: updated the answer with your query if served your requirement mark as correct

Comment: @santosh, are you referring the component file will look as below?

function (Controller) {
   "use strict";
   return Controller.extend("sap.ui.demo.wt.controller.App",{
 checkDone: function (oEvent) {
                 var check = oEvent.getParameter("selected");
                if (check===true){
               this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(true);
    onAfterRendering : function(){
   $(".placeholder .sapMInputBaseInner").attr("placeholder", "Your placeholder Text");
}
           }else{
           this.getView().byId("i1").setEnabled(false);